# XMPP XEP-0016: What is the difference between default privacy list and active privacy list?

Tags: xmpp

I am developing a chat application and for that i was reading [XMPP XEP-0016](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0016.html) for privacy settings. I am very confused between default list and active list. Which type of list should i use for privacy settings?
I don't want to waste much time on this. Help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not that obvious defined in XEP-0016, but there a few hints about the different semantics. For example XEP-16 Section 2 states that the extension is able to

> Setting, changing, or declining the default list (i.e., the list that
>   is active by default).

Further in 2.2 we find

> The default list applies to the user as a whole, and is processed if
>   there is no active list set for the target session/resource to which a
>   stanza is addressed, or if there are no current sessions for the user.

To sum up: The **default list** is used as default, hence the name, if no other list is specified by the client when enabling privacy lists. The **active list** is the list currently enforced by the server and applied to the session.

Comment: Thanks, So server automatically makes default list as active list for the session?

Comment: and i want to know how many active list of user can be on server?

Comment: @JagveerSinghRajput you can have one list marked as default - it will be activated by server on session start, and you can activate different list manually and it will be applied for all user sessions, so only one active list.

Comment: @vitalyster if i don't make any default list and create all list manually . Will they work for all user session without having to activate them by client on each login.

Comment: and one more question can we block a particular type of iq?

Comment: @vitalyster Privacy lists are enforced on a per session base, not per user. The same user can have multiple sessions with different privacy lists.